# How to stretch a div from certain position to the bottom of the page?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to stretch a div from it's current position to the end of the page. How can I do so? This is my code:

```
<div style="text-align:center; font-weight:bold; font-size:small; background-color:Silver; position:absolute; width:100%">Copyright © Aradmey<br /><%= GetDomain() %></div>
```

The div is not placed at the top of the page, it's just the footer and I can't get it working right..

Currently, the page looks like [this](http://prntscr.com/6in2xy). I want it to look like [this](http://prntscr.com/6in36x), but without it stretching so much to the bottom that it makes it scrollable. I want it to stretch only if it hasn't reached the bottom yet.

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest.

```css
html,body{height: 100%;}
.stretch{
  height: 100%;
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}
.stretch .left{
  display: table-cell;
  width: 40%;
  background: #333;
}
.stretch .right{
  display: table-cell;
  width: 60%;
  background: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div class="stretch">
  <div class="left"></div>
  <div class="right"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't need two `div`s on the same line. I need one div to be stretched to the bottom..

Comment: you can remove one div if you don't want
just make width: 100% if you remove one

Answer (score 0):

in the future the html and css should be in different classes like this:
[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r2u6e8es/)

with ur code u just need to add the "bottom:0;" to ur style: [print](http://prntscr.com/6imzwb)

```
CSS
#footer{
    text-align:center;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:small; 
    background-color:Silver;
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    bottom: 0;
}

HTML
<div id="footer">Copyright © Aradmey<br /><%= GetDomain() %></div>
```